# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource using AWS API Gateway with AWS Lambda

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, fetch

I am using `AWS API gateway` with `AWS Lambda` in my backend. I have enabled `cors` for my endpoint. But when I run the endpoint on the browser I am only getting the following error

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Using `redux thunk`, my actions file is as follows

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export function fetchUsers(){

return (dispatch) => {

  const headers={
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization":cookies.get('idToken')
  }

  return fetch(`${url}/accounts`,{method:"GET",headers:headers }).then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

I also observe that my `OPTIONS` and `GET` requests are able to give `200 OK` response in the network options on the web browser. The current API takes about 11 sec to give a response.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Are you by any chance using an additional port aside 8080?

Comment: @YonahDissen I am not using anything on port 8080 other than my application

Comment: My only other guess would be that you missed something in the when you enabled cors. You can post your code and I'll take a look at it...

Comment: I am using serverless to deploy aws functions

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to troubleshoot without knowing what other steps you've taken but see if any of the following helps:

1. If you've enabled CORS **don't forget to perform "Deploy API"**.  I always forget this
2. Try including these `headers` properties (see below) in the lambda response if the APIGateway endpoint is configured to `Use Lambda Proxy integration` under `Integration Request` (it's a checkbox, at the time of this writing).  If using other types of integrations you'll need to manually set the headers in the endpoint's response/mapping settings.

   ```
   {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
       , //other optional entries here
   }
   ```